# St_split return the original line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

I would like to split a linestring with postgis.

My function :

```
  @distance_b_to_a = Track.find_by_sql(
  ["SELECT
    ST_Split(line, ST_Closestpoint(pta,line))  AS dst_line
    FROM (
      SELECT
        'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(1.391991 46.441430,1.506078 46.556788)'::geometry line,
        'SRID=4326;POINT(1.396636962890625 46.442352066959174)'::geometry pta,
    ) data"
  ])
```

and my show :

```
  <p>Test : <%= @distance_b_to_a.first.dst_line %></p>
```

return my original linestring :

```
Test : GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (1.391991 46.44143, 1.506078 46.556788))
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: A line can be split by a point on an existing line vertex only (unlike when splitting using a crossing line). See this interesting [doc](https://mygisnotes.wordpress.com/2017/01/01/split-lines-with-points-the-postgis-way/)

Comment: @JGH as always a straightforward answer! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ST_Split`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html) returns a collection of geometries resulting by splitting a geometry, so I'm afraid it's the expected result, since your `LineString` has only two points.

Consider the following `LineString` ...

```
LINESTRING(18.6435 42.5412,18.8440 42.5453,18.846 42.3994)
```

[image]

.. and run this query, which applies `ST_Split` using the second point from the above mentioned `LineString`:

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT 
    'SRID=4326;POINT(18.8440 42.5453)'::GEOMETRY AS pta,
    'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(18.6435 42.5412,18.8440 42.5453,18.846 42.3994)'::GEOMETRY AS line
)
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(
  ST_Split(line,
    ST_ClosestPoint(pta,line))) FROM j
```

... returning a `GeometryCollection` with two `LineStrings`:

```
                                                st_astext                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(18.6435 42.5412,18.844 42.5453),LINESTRING(18.844 42.5453,18.846 42.3994))
(1 Zeile)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, It's very clear ;) 
Is it a method to get the nearest point existing on the linestring and split the line with him ?

Comment: It does almost exactly what you were doing in your question, namely getting the closest point to a given coordinate and using this point to split the linestring. Glad it helped :-) btw, the link provided by @JGH is worth reading!